# How to automate commands on Cygwin

Tags: automation, sh, cygwin

Hi I am looking to automate my file transfering to my Jailbroken iPhone over USB with a bash file. Which will launch the relay then do the file transfers

With this [here](https://bookandcode.com/tech/how-to-ssh-to-a-jailbroken-ios-device-over-usb/) I installed and successfully transfered files to my iPhone with cygwin but now I want to automate the file transfer.

First I need to start the relay with cygwin and those commands are required

```
cd pyusbmux/python-client/
chmod +x *
./tclrelay.py -t 22:2222
```

so I created a .sh file that does it but when I launch it cygwin gives me those errors

This is what should happen on the left and the result of the script on the right
[image]

How can I make cygwin open with thoses commands

Comment: Please don't (only) post images of text!

Comment: `\r` indicates Windows line endings where unix line endings are expected. Use `dos2unix`. This should fix the first and third.

Comment: The other problem suggests that the PATH is incorrect. Not sure how that happened. Well, I do, the command wasn't run from a login shell or one of its descendants. But not sure how you achieved that.

Comment: @ikegami : The problem here seems to be indeed that `sh` is running as a non-login shell. This is possible, if you for instance invoke it directly from a Windows cmd shell.  As a first attempt to fix this, I would explicitly use bash and place a `#!/usr/bin/bash -l`  into the script. However, the OP should show of course *how*  and *from where* the script was started.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to be sure that `tcpON.sh` has proper line termination with `d2u` of `dos2unix` package:

```
d2u tcpON.sh
```

You should add a proper SHEBANG on the first line of your script
https://linuxize.com/post/bash-shebang/

```
#!/bin/bash
cd /cygdrive/e/Grez/Desktop
cd pyusbmux/python-client/
chmod +x *
./tclrelay.py -t 22:2222
```

You can use as base the `Cygwin.bat` and make a `tcpON.bat` batch file like:

```
C:
chdir c:\cygwin64\bin

bash --login /cygdrive/e/Grez/Desktop/tcpON.sh
```

Verify the proper `cd` command to be sure that you are always in the expected directory.

It is not the only way but probably the most flexible (IMHO)